# Whenever I try to safely remove any USB device, I keep getting this error. "WMS Volume Sideband 7" error issue

Tags: usb, usb-storage, eject

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHUqG.png)

I am unable to fix this USB issue. It keeps appearing when I try to safely remove it. Normally, the error should be GENERIC VOLUME but in my case, it shows WMS Volume Sideband 7 error. What is this WMS sideband and how can I fix it so that I can safely remove device without taking risk of losing data in it ? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Open: Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off

Turn off "MultiPoint Connector":
[image: Picture]

Reboot computer